# Svelte - binding inputs

Tags: input, svelte

I am working on a unit conversion application to convert medical units from US units to International (SI) units. I am trying to use separate inputs for each US and SI conversion so that when one input value is changed, the other input changes based on the new value. Each conversion uses a factor for the calculation. I have a simple example set up which will populate the input values on load but I am unable to get the input change function to work.

[REPL example](https://svelte.dev/repl/65d32c1365c3469b9f58a0685e22844d?version=3.12.1)

Here is my code:

```
<script>
let units = [{
        "name": "Acetaminophen",
        "specimen": "Serum, Plasma",
        "conventionalRange": "10-30",
        "conventionalUnit": "µg/mL",
        "factor": "6.614",
        "siRange": "66-200",
        "siUnit": "µmol/L",
        "siValue": "66",
        "usValue": "10"
  }, {
        "name": "Acetoacetate",
        "specimen": "Serum, Plasma",
        "conventionalRange": "<1",
        "conventionalUnit": "mg/dL",
        "factor": "97.95",
        "siRange": "<100",
        "siUnit": "µmol/L",
        "siValue": "100",
        "usValue": "1"
  }, {
        "name": "Acetone",
        "specimen": "Serum, Plasma",
        "conventionalRange": "<1.0",
        "conventionalUnit": "mg/dL",
        "factor": "0.172",
        "siRange": "<0.17",
        "siUnit": "mmol/L",
        "siValue": "0.17",
        "usValue": "1.0"
  }, {
        "name": "Acid phosphatase",
        "specimen": "Serum",
        "conventionalRange": "<5.5",
        "conventionalUnit": "U/L",
        "factor": "16.667",
        "siRange": "<90",
        "siUnit": "nkat/L",
        "siValue": "90",
        "usValue": "5.5"
  }, {
        "name": "Activated partial thromboplastin time (APTT)",
        "specimen": "Whole blood",
        "conventionalRange": "25-40",
        "conventionalUnit": "s",
        "factor": "1",
        "siRange": "25-40",
        "siUnit": "s",
        "siValue": "25",
        "usValue": "25"
  }
    ]

    let factor = '';
    let siValue = '';
    let usValue = '';

    function setBothFromSI(value) {
    siValue = +value;
    usValue = +(siValue / factor).toFixed(2);
   }
   function setBothFromUS(value) {
    usValue = +value;
    siValue = +(usValue * factor).toFixed(2);;
   }
 </script>
 <style>input{max-width:150px}
.bold{font-weight:600;}
 </style>

 {#each units as { usValue,siValue,siUnit,siRange,conventionalUnit,conventionalRange,specimen,name, factor}, i}
 <p class=bold >{name}</p>
 <label>
US Value
 <input value={usValue} on:input="{e => setBothFromUS(e.target.value)}" min="" type=number placeholder=" US">
</label>
<label>
SI Value
<input value={siValue} on:input="{e => setBothFromSI(e.target.value)}" min="" type=number placeholder="SI">
</label>

 {/each}
```

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like the only issue is that in `setBothFromSI` and `setBothFromUS`, you're trying to update the variables `siValue` and `usValue`. But nothing is rendering those variables, your inputs are actually rendering the values contained in each `unit`, because of the `{#each units as { usValue, siValue } }` block

So in those `setBoth` functions, you probably want to be updating the values inside of `units`, like this:

```
function setBothFromSI(value, i) {
    const { factor } = units[i];

    units[i].siValue = +value;
    units[i].usValue = +(value / factor).toFixed(2);
}
function setBothFromUS(value, i) {
    const { factor } = units[i];

    units[i].usValue = +value;
    units[i].siValue = +(value * factor).toFixed(2);;
}
```

And then make sure to pass the index into those functions like this

```html
<input value={usValue} on:input="{e => setBothFromUS(e.target.value, i)}" min="" type=number placeholder=" US">
```

Here's an [updated REPL](https://svelte.dev/repl/4aaf6f486c0846559d88e18fdc42add0?version=3.12.1)

Comment: Thanks for the help. One issue I see, is if you delete one of the inputs value, the other input does not change  and if you then enter another value into the empty input, nothing changes until you enter a second number.

Comment: Ah oops, there was a bug in my code, it was referring to the old version of the si/us value instead of the updated version, so the calculated value was always one edit behind. Edited the answer and updated the REPL,

Comment: Thanks for your help previously! I am revisiting this REPL and thinking if there is a way besides each input changing the other as it does currently, if there is a possible way to have one single  "master" input at the top of the page where a user could enter a value and all inputs would calculate related to that entered value.  Sound too crazy? :-)